# Is it possible to point a domain to a bitbucket static site?

Tags: bitbucket, cdn

I have a domain hosted by HostMonster and I'd like to point the domain to mydomain.bitbucket.io by editing CDN settings.

What will be the host record and points to?

There are these settings to add record:

[image]

Will this work?

There is something similar done for [github static pages](https://gist.github.com/yancyn/18b07b7ec600812b15f8).

Comment: Have you tried it? All you should need to do is set `Host Record` to whatever name you have on HostMonster that you want going to `mydomain.bitbucket.io` as an `ANAME`. If you don't have the name setup on HostMonster then you'll also create a `CNAME` for it that points to the IP address or the primary domain name you have setup on HostMonster.

Comment: I tried set Host Record to `www` and points to mydomain.bitbucket.io as an CNAME. It didn't work. I also have servernames set for the hostgator host because that's where I have hosting set up currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Bitbucket support:

> Currently, it's not possible to configure custom domains for bitbucket
> static websites. We already have a feature request for that
> functionality, which you can find in the following link:
>
> https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-11257
>
> I would suggest you to add your vote there, since this helps both
> developers and product managers to understand the interest. Also, make
> sure you add yourself as a watcher in case you want to receive
> first-hand updates from that ticket. Please note that all features are
> implemented with this policy in mind.